# dpkg error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure)

Tags: keyboard, dpkg

New Atomic Pi, installed VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

issued: "sudo apt-get upgrade"

```
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.178ubuntu2.9) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.config: 1: eval: en: not found
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 installed keyboard-configuration package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
```

I don't have a window panel to open the keyboard configuration dialog - can this be resolved for en_US keyboard by editing a file?

Thanks, Morris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Comments:**

`language-pack-en` need to be reinstalled. Reinstall that using

```
sudo apt install --reinstall language-pack-en
```

Try `sudo apt upgrade` again.

Comment: The immediate upgrade after --reinstall failed.  Upgrade, reboot, then upgrade had success.  Thanks, morris

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT try to uninstall keyboard-configuration because it will uninstall the xserver!

So now I've reinstall lubuntu-gtx-desktop and a reboot gets me to a working system. I then ran apt update; apt upgrade and had the keyboard selections show up and it looks like apt is now happy.  Rebooted again and all is well that I can tell.